# How to remove the word Authors(s) from WordPress twentytwelve postmetadata

Tags: wordpress

In the postmetadata WordPress inserts the word Author(s) for each post followed by the name of the author. I want to remove that word but still have the name of the author show up. Anybody know how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you inside the loop with this? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author

Comment: Find the template file (page.php, single.php, etc.), locate this below the post, usually in the <div class="post"> and remove/comment out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the words in index.php and single.php. I just deleted the words and moved the files into my child theme. Good to go.